# updating to OpenGL 3.2 from OpenGL 2.1

Tags: linux, opengl, opengl-es, archlinux

I am trying to install obs-studio https://obsproject.com/ on arch linux but its documentation says

> Linux
>
> NOTE: OpenGL 3.2 or later is required to use OBS Multiplatform on
>   Linux. You can check what version of OpenGL is supported by your
>   system by typing the following into the terminal:
>
> ```
> glxinfo | grep "OpenGL"
> ```

so my system output for

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL"
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ironlake Mobile 
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 13.0.1
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 2.0 Mesa 13.0.1
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0.16
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

it says `2.1` so how could i upgrade it to `3.2`

as from arch inux documentation https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/intel_graphics  i have already installed `mesa-libgl` ,  `xf86-video-intel` package.

result from chrome://gpu/

```
Initialization time     118
```

> ```
> In-process GPU    false
> ```

```
Sandboxed   true
GPU0    VENDOR = 0x8086, DEVICE= 0x0046
Optimus     false
AMD switchable  false
Driver vendor   Mesa
Driver version  13.0.1
Driver date     
Pixel shader version    1.20
Vertex shader version   1.20
Max. MSAA samples   0
Machine model name  
Machine model version   
GL_VENDOR   Intel Open Source Technology Center
GL_RENDERER     Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ironlake Mobile
GL_VERSION  2.1 Mesa 13.0.1
GL_EXTENSIONS   GL_ARB_multisample GL_EXT_abgr GL_EXT_bgra GL_EXT_blend_color GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_EXT_blend_subtract GL_EXT_copy_texture GL_EXT_polygon_offset GL_EXT_subtexture GL_EXT_texture_object GL_EXT_vertex_array GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array GL_EXT_texture GL_EXT_texture3D GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip GL_ARB_point_parameters GL_EXT_draw_range_elements GL_EXT_packed_pixels GL_EXT_point_parameters GL_EXT_rescale_normal GL_EXT_separate_specular_color GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp GL_SGIS_texture_lod GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB GL_ARB_multitexture GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1 GL_ARB_texture_cube_map GL_ARB_texture_env_add GL_ARB_transpose_matrix GL_EXT_blend_func_separate GL_EXT_fog_coord GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays GL_EXT_secondary_color GL_EXT_texture_env_add GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias GL_INGR_blend_func_separate GL_NV_blend_square GL_NV_light_max_exponent GL_NV_texgen_reflection GL_NV_texture_env_combine4 GL_S3_s3tc GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp GL_ARB_texture_compression GL_EXT_framebuffer_object GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc GL_EXT_texture_env_combine GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3 GL_MESA_window_pos GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil GL_NV_texture_rectangle GL_ARB_depth_texture GL_ARB_shadow GL_ARB_texture_env_combine GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3 GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat GL_ARB_window_pos GL_EXT_stencil_two_side GL_EXT_texture_cube_map GL_NV_depth_clamp GL_APPLE_packed_pixels GL_APPLE_vertex_array_object GL_ARB_draw_buffers GL_ARB_fragment_program GL_ARB_fragment_shader GL_ARB_shader_objects GL_ARB_vertex_program GL_ARB_vertex_shader GL_ATI_draw_buffers GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3 GL_ATI_texture_float GL_EXT_shadow_funcs GL_EXT_stencil_wrap GL_MESA_pack_invert GL_NV_primitive_restart GL_ARB_depth_clamp GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow GL_ARB_half_float_pixel GL_ARB_point_sprite GL_ARB_shading_language_100 GL_ARB_sync GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate GL_OES_read_format GL_ARB_color_buffer_float GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc GL_ARB_texture_float GL_ARB_texture_rectangle GL_EXT_packed_float GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1 GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc GL_EXT_texture_rectangle GL_EXT_texture_sRGB GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent GL_ARB_framebuffer_object GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil GL_APPLE_object_purgeable GL_ARB_vertex_array_object GL_ATI_separate_stencil GL_EXT_draw_buffers2 GL_EXT_draw_instanced GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters GL_EXT_texture_array GL_EXT_texture_integer GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode GL_OES_EGL_image GL_AMD_performance_monitor GL_ARB_copy_buffer GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float GL_ARB_draw_instanced GL_ARB_half_float_vertex GL_ARB_instanced_arrays GL_ARB_map_buffer_range GL_ARB_texture_rg GL_ARB_texture_swizzle GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra GL_EXT_texture_swizzle GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra GL_NV_conditional_render GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility GL_ARB_debug_output GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions GL_ARB_provoking_vertex GL_ARB_sampler_objects GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod GL_ARB_texture_query_lod GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev GL_EXT_provoking_vertex GL_EXT_texture_snorm GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba GL_NV_texture_barrier GL_ARB_get_program_binary GL_ARB_robustness GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3 GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5 GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage GL_ARB_internalformat_query GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment GL_ARB_shading_language_packing GL_ARB_texture_storage GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax GL_ARB_arrays_of_arrays GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object GL_ARB_copy_image GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata GL_ARB_program_interface_query GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding GL_KHR_debug GL_KHR_robustness GL_ARB_buffer_storage GL_ARB_clear_texture GL_ARB_internalformat_query2 GL_ARB_multi_bind GL_ARB_seamless_cubemap_per_texture GL_ARB_shader_draw_parameters GL_ARB_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge GL_ARB_vertex_type_10f_11f_11f_rev GL_INTEL_performance_query GL_ARB_clip_control GL_ARB_get_texture_sub_image GL_ARB_pipeline_statistics_query GL_ARB_texture_barrier GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced GL_KHR_context_flush_control
Disabled Extensions     GL_ARB_occlusion_query GL_ARB_occlusion_query2 GL_ARB_timer_query GL_EXT_timer_query
Window system binding vendor    SGI
Window system binding version   1.4
Window system binding extensions    GLX_ARB_create_context GLX_ARB_create_context_profile GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB GLX_ARB_multisample GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB GLX_EXT_import_context GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap GLX_EXT_visual_info GLX_EXT_visual_rating GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer GLX_OML_swap_method GLX_SGI_swap_control GLX_SGIS_multisample GLX_SGIX_fbconfig GLX_SGIX_pbuffer GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group GLX_INTEL_swap_event
Window manager  GNOME Shell
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP     GNOME
Compositing manager     Yes
Direct rendering    Yes
Reset notification strategy     0x8261
GPU process crash count     0
```

i see that `In-process GPU    false`  does this means i have to buy a external gpu

Comment: Which gpu do you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenGL 3.x is nt supported on Intel Ironlake. You will need at least Intel Sandy Bridge to get modern OpenGL on Intel GPUs.

You *can* get OpenGL 3.3 from mesa's `llvmpipe` or `softpipe` software renderers by setting the `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1` environment variable. However, since this will not use the GPU at all, it will be rather slow.

Comment: could you please explain a little how to install llvmpipe on arch. i have installed llvm.

Comment: `llvmpipe` is a part of mesa3d (which you are already using). I don't know how arch does package this stuff, though, so I don't know if you need any additional packages, or if you have it already. You can just try `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 glxinfo | grep OpenGL` and see if you get it instead of the inel ironlake backend you got before.

Comment: it says OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 13.0.1 but obs-studio wants 3.2 :(

Comment: OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.9, 128 bits)
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 13.0.1
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 13.0.1
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 13.0.1

Comment: Well, as per the spec, OpenGL implementations are not required to support compatibility profiles. Mesa only supports core profiles, and as you can see: `OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 13.0.1`. If an application says it requires OpenGL 3.2 and does _not_ use a core profile. the application is just faulty. It should say so if i requires optional features. However, it is not even clear that your app does not use a core profile. Have you actually tried running it with that enivornment variable?

Comment: it worked `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 obs` thanks a lot

Comment: I am new to OpenGL.  You said "OpenGL 3.x is nt supported on Intel Ironlake. You will need at least Intel Sandy Bridge to get modern OpenGL on Intel GPUs."  Do you mean that even if I get a newer GPU, the system just can not support OpenGL 3.x?   My CPU micro-arch is Westmere, two generation earlier than Sandy Bridge.  BTW, I cannot find "Ironlake" micro-arch from wiki page of Intel's micro-arch list... What is Ironlake?

Comment: @RobinHsu: Ironlake was Intel's name for the first gen Intel HD graphics which came with Westmere. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Graphics_Technology#Westmere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Graphics_Technology#Westmere), so no, it does not support decent OpenGL. But if you get another GPU, it is up to the new GPU, of course.

Comment: This resolved my issue trying to get fyrox to run on old hardware. `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 cargo run --package editor --release`. Error I received was thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Custom("CreationErrors([OpenGlVersionNotSupported, OsError(\"GL context creation failed\")])")',`

Answer (score -3):

[Chris Forbes](https://github.com/chrisforbes/mesa/tree/ilk-glsl-130) has a (don't know how much) experimental mesa branch that should get you at least GLSL 1.30

You'd still miss an [extension](https://people.freedesktop.org/~imirkin/glxinfo/#v=Mesa%2017.2.0&p=compat) for full OGL 3 compliancy.. But I'd guess like it would be a step forward?